# validation error while sending email

Tags: javascript, php, email

I want to send an email. it gives me validation error 'fields are mandatory' when I click on `email` buttons and page get refreshed, even-though i entered correct email id. If i entered correct email id then also it gives error.
I don't know where i am going wrong. Can anybody tell me. Here is my php code:

```
function validation1()
{
    document.getElementById("emailid").innerHTML="";

    var emailpattern=/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
    if(document.form1.email.value=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("emailid").innerHTML="fields are mandetory";
        document.form1.email.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if(!emailpattern.test(document.form1.email.value))
    {
        document.getElementById("emailid").innerHTML="enter valid id";
        document.form1.email.focus();
        return false;
    }
return true;
}

<?php include 'send-email.php';?>
<form name="form1" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="email" value="email" onclick="return validation1()" />
<input type="text" size="50" name="email" id="email" placeholder="*************" />
<span id="emailid"></span>
</form>
```

send-email.php code

```
<?php include 'connection.php'; ?>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
@$email=$_POST["email"];

$email=strip_tags($_POST["email"]);
$email=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,trim($email));

$to="sa@vs.com";
$to=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,trim($to));
$headers="From:".$email;
$message="Interested in VAPT";
$subject="email id";
if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
{
    $email="'".$email."'";

    $sql="insert into email_to_admin values($email)";
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
        {
            die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }
}

mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try below for mail :-

```
if($_POST["email"]){  // Add this if condition so that your mail will be send when button gets clicked.

$to="sa@vs.com";
$to=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,trim($to));
$headers="From:".$email;
$message="Interested in VAPT";
$subject="email id";
if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
{
    $email="'".$email."'";

    $sql="insert into email_to_admin values($email)";
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
        {
            die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }
}


}
```

Comment: At least put in some explanation instead of just handing over code that may or may not work for OP.

Comment: Yup. It's very easy i was mad, BDW thank you so much. error has gone.but one thing when i click on email button , it gives me validation error. i did it correctly but dont know why does it come.

Comment: What document.form1.email.value gives you? Please alert it

Comment: when i click on email button, it gives the validation error 'all fields are mandetory'  when i entered correct id.

Comment: alert this value :- document.form1.email.value

Comment: i alert it, it gave a blank filed mean values is not getting. so what i do to get values and remove error.

Comment: Add id in your input field and call it like this in validation :-

document.getElementById("email_id").value

Answer (score 0):

You have no `if()` statement to control when the mail is sent. As soon as the page load, you instantly mail. Use

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {}
```

Comment: Yup. It's very easy i was mad, BDW thank you so much. error has gone.but one thing when i click on email button , it gives me validation error. i did it correctly but dont know why does it come.

Answer (score 0):

```
     if(isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["email"] !="" )
     {

             //send the email

     }
```

Personally I would recommend also placing an antispam captcha, this way it will make sure that the new rendom value is not the same

And since you have another step which helps you, you may also mark the email address plus some other value like subject unique in the email_to_admin MySQL Table, if a record is inserted, you carry on

```
  $sql="insert into email_to_admin values($email , $subject)";
  .....................
  $num = @mysql_affected_rows();
  if($num > 0)
  {
      //semd the email
  }
```